# What is the difference between CONSTANT : value and CONSTANT = value?

Tags: javascript

I´m learning javascript and I have found a file with many assignments done with the operand ':' instead of '='. In spite of the title of the question, I have seen it in non-constants too. What´s the point for that? What´s the meaning of the ':' operand here?
Thank you.

```
 var MyApplet = {

    FILE_NAME : 'filename.ext',

    CUSTOM_ARGUMENTS : null,

    BUFFER_SIZE : 1024 * 1024, (...)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Comment: What is the meaning of `:` … where? It means different things in different places.

Comment: @richieahb — That's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: think of the ':' values as a bit like fields in a Java class.

Comment: Please start off with a basic JS tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no constants there at all.

That is [an object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

A new object is created, with the property names and values described in the body, and assigned to `MyApplet`.

The assignment operator (`=`) is used when assigning a value to a variable or property in most circumstances outside of literals.

(NB: The usual conventions for JavaScript avoid using ALL CAPS for names of things, and avoid starting variable names with a capital letter unless they hold a constructor function. The code you have is therefore not idiomatic JavaScript.)

Comment: Thank you, I will study about object literal. However, about your last note, Google js style guide recommeds to name constants LIKE_THIS. [link](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Naming#Naming)